# use the name of combo box in java for actionperformed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have 2 or more combo box and I want to use from (ActionListener)for these combo boxes but I dont know     how I can use from name of combo boxes in a (actionPerformed)

```
comboBox1= new JComboBox(items);    
comboBox1.addActionListener(this);    
comboBox1.setName("com");    
comboBox2= new JComboBox(items);    
comboBox2.addActionListener(this);    
comboBox2.setName("com");    

@Override    
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
}
```

but I dont know how I can use from these combo boxes in this (actionPerformed) because I have 2 combo box and I can not use from one of them.
thanks

Comment: What does [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) (supplied to the listener callback) contain?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please show us some code/pictures of the issue that you are talking about so that we can further assist you with your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`JComboBox#setActionCommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setActionCommand(java.lang.String)), which will set the `actionCommand` property of the `ActionEvent` when triggered
- Compare the `source` property of the `ActionEvent` against instances of the combo boxes
- Use a single `ActionListener` for each combo box
- Use the `Action` API instead.  See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for details

Comment: xxxClientProperty should be standard way, sure without Swing Action, then everything could be easier, I'd be use ItemListener for JComboBox (if the event notify another, diferrent Object)

Comment: `xxxClientProperty` always seems a bit dirty to me (but that's just me). In this case `setActionCommand` would be the best solution, but I'd prefer to use a dedicated `ActionListener` or `Action`. Not really found much use of an `ItemListener` in these cases, personally prefer `ActionListener`, but that comes down to needs